# How to send sms to localhost in j2me?

Tags: sms, java-me

Im not familiar with the J2me framework, I would like to know how to send a message to the local phone.

I am just developing an application, which set ExamDates and if I login this application and I have exam scheduled within 2 days I would like my app to send me an SMS letting me know that I have something schedule ...

I know how to send an sms but how to do it to locahost, I don't want to put my number in it, just want to send it to localhost. Is it possible ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't do this, I'm afraid!

Two options:

- Set up a server somewhere which is capable of sending the SMS reminder at the right time for you, and communicate to that server from your MIDlet, to set the reminder
- To achieve a "reminder" effect without using SMS, read up about the [PushRegistry](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/PushRegistry.html) facility in MIDP, and its `RegisterAlarm` function.